# How does Spanish handle people that identify as binary as far as with noun + verb agreement?

Tags: traducción, gramática, uso-de-palabras, género, rae

As gender has become a more varied identification than just male and female for people, how is it dealt with in a language so entrenched in gender?

would a binary person be - ellos and use the plural verb form even though it is a single person?   Or is there a specific word?

Comment: Hello @Lynn Coppolino, welcome to the forum. I am afraid that your question lacks the proper formatting. There's not a clear question nor any apparent research. The only way to answer to the question as it is articulated, is by posting opinions which are off-topic. I would suggest you to edit your post to include a specific question.

Comment: Aclaro que estás equivocade. La pregunta está meramente basada en prejuicios creados por los mismos anglosajones para hacer un intento (futil) para demostrar la superioridad del inglés. Absolutamente TODO lo contrario ocurre. El inglés es mucho maś sexista que el español y te das cuenta porque no pueden omitir los pronombres. Sus conversaciones son: 'que HE hizo esto', 'que SHE hizo aquello', etc. Mientras que en español es 'que hizo esto' y punto, no es necesario aclarar quién. Aprendan a prescindir de los pronombres y después podremos tener un debate que valga la pena.